# Getting insert id with insert PDO MySQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im getting to grips with the basics of PDO.

However Im trying to get the id of the inserted row, Im using:

```
$query = $system->db->prepare("INSERT INTO {$this->_table} (name,description) VALUES (:name,:description)");
$query->execute(array('name'=>$name,'description'=>$description));
```

The tutorials I have come across are regarding transactions, however I am not using transactions!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're probably looking for [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). "Returns the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value".

```
$insertedId = $system->db->lastInsertId() ;
```

Comment: Ah ha thanks! For some reason I was trying to call it on the $query variable.

Answer (score 10):

Pay attention when using transactions.

If you call `lastInsertedId` after you call `commit`, `lastInsertedId` will return 0 instead of the id.
Call `lastInsertedId` right after `execute`, but before `commit`.

```
$this->db->beginTransaction();
$this->stmt->execute();
$id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
$this->db->commit();
```