# How to populate a look up table with a dual primary key?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database and this includes three tables as follows:

-Player

-Player Previous Clubs

-Previous Clubs

The 'Player Previous Clubs' table is a look up table as there is a many-to-many relationship between player and previous clubs.

Now I have the below code which successfully populates the 'player' table and 'previous clubs table' from a single form.

```
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

//PLAYER TABLE INSERT
try
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO player SET
            name = :name,
            age = :age,
            position = :position,
            height = :height,
            weight = :weight,
            satscore = :satscore,
            gpa = :gpa';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
    $s->bindValue(':age', $_POST['age']);
    $s->bindValue(':position', $_POST['position']);
    $s->bindValue(':height', $_POST['height']);
    $s->bindValue(':weight', $_POST['weight']);
    $s->bindValue(':satscore', $_POST['satscore']);
    $s->bindValue(':gpa', $_POST['gpa']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding submitted player profile.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

//PREVIOUS CLUBS TABLE INSERT
try
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO previousclubs SET
            name = :previousclubs';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':previousclubs', $_POST['previousclubs']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding previous club.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

header('Location: .');
exit();
}
```

I am unsure of how to populate the look up table (player previous clubs) as the values that it requires are not passed in via the form, they are generated via the auto increment functionality.

The table consists of two fields.  One is the primary key value of the player table and the other is the primary key of the previous clubs table.

Together these two fields form a joint primary key.

Any help on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Okay I now have the below code:

```
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

//PLAYER TABLE INSERT
try
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO player SET
            name = :name,
            age = :age,
            position = :position,
            height = :height,
            weight = :weight,
            satscore = :satscore,
            gpa = :gpa';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
    $s->bindValue(':age', $_POST['age']);
    $s->bindValue(':position', $_POST['position']);
    $s->bindValue(':height', $_POST['height']);
    $s->bindValue(':weight', $_POST['weight']);
    $s->bindValue(':satscore', $_POST['satscore']);
    $s->bindValue(':gpa', $_POST['gpa']);
    $s->execute();

    $one = $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding submitted player profile.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

//PREVIOUS CLUBS TABLE INSERT
try
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO previousclubs SET
            name = :previousclubs';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':previousclubs', $_POST['previousclubs']);
    $s->execute();

    $two = $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding previous club.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

//PLAYER PREVIOUS CLUB INSERT
try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO playerpreviousclubs SET
            playerid = '$one',
            previousclubid = '$two'";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':playerid', $_POST['playerid']);
    $s->bindValue(':previousclubid', $_POST['previousclubid']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding player previous club look up data.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

//LINKS TABLE INSERT
try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO links SET
            link = :link,
            playerid = '$one'";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':link', $_POST['link']);
    $s->bindValue(':playerid', $_POST['playerid']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding link for player.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

header('Location: .');
exit();
}
```

This gives me the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: playerid in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\connect\players\index.php on line 84

Notice: Undefined index: previousclubid in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\connect\players\index.php on line 85

Notice: Undefined index: playerid in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\connect\players\index.php on line 103

Error adding link for player.SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

If I remove all of the code under '//LINKS TABLE INSERT' then it works so I assume the problem is here but I need this table to store the $one value also.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting insert id with insert PDO MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742554/getting-insert-id-with-insert-pdo-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID generated for the inserted player and club rows are available in `$pdo->lastInsertId()` after you execute each of those queries. So after each `execute()`, store the inserted ID in a variable to use in the later query.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your reply.  Am nearly there but am getting an error when trying to assign the variable that stores the id to a second table.  Please see my update to my original post.  It's strange that it doesn't work when it is used on the links table.

Comment: You put `$one` and `$two` directly in the query, instead of placeholders. You then tried to bind values to the placeholders you didn't create. You also tried to bind keys from `$_POST` that didn't exist, instead of `$one` and `$two`, which are where the values are. I think you copied and pasted too much without thinking about what your code does :)

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the reply, you had in accordance with the title of this question already answered the question so sorry about that and thanks for the extra advice.