# Creating unique billing identifier

Tags: php, mysql, identifier

I would like to create a unique billing identifier/number. I want it to be a combination of a constant string, year and an additional number. For example "ABC-2013-100001". How can I do that so I will be definitely sure that the billing identifier is unique? I was thinking about maintaing a billing_id like a primary key that would be unique and autoincrement. Then I would  just select max(billing_id) to get the last one add 1 to it and the prefix "ABC-2013" and then insert it into the table. The problem is that this is a 3 step way. Select, do something, insert. I am afraid that it might happen something like, when 2 users will do this at the same time, every one selects the same number, so technically they insert the same identifier. Am I wrong and overreacting or is this kind of generating unique ids common? Should I take a different approach?

**EDIT**

Ok so I did something like this:

```
$data = array(
    'billing_identifier' => 'law-'.$year."-".$this->db->insert_id()
);
// inserting into billing_identifiers
    $this->db->insert('billing_identifiers', $data);

    $bill_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

but the  $this->db->insert_id() is 0 at the beginning which makes sense and after calling the insert function it gets the last id. Isnt there a way I can do that in one shot?

Comment: Use [last inserted id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742554/getting-insert-id-with-insert-pdo-mysql). This is` the PDO version; call it immediately after the insert. **Never MAX.** Store "ABC-2013-" without the ID.

Comment: It may also come in handy to make the field unique in the database just to be sure.

Comment: are gaps in sequential numbers welcome? (AFAIK possible issue on `InnoDB`)

Comment: Thank you, I will probably go for the `$this->db->insert_id();` I am using the Codeigniter fw. And I will absolutely make the column unique, but I dont want to always check if there is such number or not. Thats why I asked, if there is an atomic way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this, it will give you the primary id.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","pass","db");
//query here
$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$bill_id = 'ABC-2013-'. $id;

?>
```

changed because of "doesn't fit the question"...

Comment: What? rand is getting a random number between the two given numbers. Don't know what it has to do about uniquenes...

Comment: The user specifically asked for a unique number. `rand()` can give the same number twice

Comment: your `$newran` can be same value multiple times and OP doesn't want that

Comment: REALLY?... so, your telling me that rand can possibly produce the same number twice... i just learned something new -_-

Comment: @user2067005 If you already knew that, you haven't read the question. If there's a possibility for your function to return the same number twice it's simply not unique, and uniqueness is the core of what the user asked for.

Comment: @mpapec after looking at my code. ya, that would of been a very, very bad idea xD

Answer (score 0):

There is a MySQL function for getting the last inserted ID, and one to pad a string with for example zeroes:

```
CONCAT(
    'ABC-2013-',
    LPAD(
         LAST_INSERT_ID()+1,
         6,
         '0'
    )
)
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()+1` is the id currently being inserted.

`LPAD(str, length, pad)` pads the new ID with zeroes in front of it.

`CONCAT(..., ...)` combines to values into a string.

Insert that into the billing identifier column.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

`strtime(d/y/m) 
time object`