# Update dropdown list after adding a new data into the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown list, via `<select>`, that is being generated by a javascript code, which is also coming from my database:

```
function dirfunc(){

  var dirdiv = document.getElementById("dirdiv");
  var ahref = document.getElementById("href");
  var directidarr = new Array();
  var directorarr = new Array();

  <?php

    include("../conn.php");
    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT directorid,directorname FROM directortb")){
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($directorid,$directorname);
      $counter = 0;
      while($stmt->fetch()){
        ?>
          directidarr[<?php echo $counter; ?>] = "<?php echo $directorid; ?>";
          directorarr[<?php echo $counter; ?>] = "<?php echo $directorname; ?>";
        <?php
        $counter = $counter + 1;
      }
      $stmt->close();
    }
  ?>

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class","form-group");

  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.setAttribute("class","col-sm-2 control-label");
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Director"));

  var div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.setAttribute("class","col-sm-9");

  var sel = document.createElement("select");
  sel.setAttribute("name","director");
  sel.setAttribute("class","form-control");

  for (var x = 0; x < directidarr.length; x++){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(directorarr[x]));
    opt.setAttribute("value", directidarr[x]);
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  }

  var div3 = document.createElement("div");
  div3.setAttribute("class","col-sm-1");

  var div4 = document.createElement("div");
  div4.setAttribute("class","input-group");

  div2.appendChild(sel);
  div3.appendChild(ahref);
  div.appendChild(label);
  div.appendChild(div2);
  div.appendChild(div3);
  dirdiv.appendChild(div);

}
```

[image]

In my HTML code, where it generates the dropdown, on its right side is a button that would show a modal. In this modal is a form that would allow users to add more option for the select dropdown.

[image]

Here is the script I am using to add data without refreshing the page:

```
$(function() {
    $("#adddirector").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var directorname = $("#directorname").val();
        var dataString = 'directorname=' + directorname;

        if(directorname == '')
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeIn(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../action.php",
                data: dataString,
                success:{
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

With this form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="../action.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Director's Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="ccdiv">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="directorname" id="directorname" value="" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="adddirector" id="adddirector">Add Director <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But after adding a new data, through the form or the back-end/phpmyadmin, the dropdown is not updating. User has to still refresh the page in order for the dropdown to be updated. What am I missing or should do with my script?

Comment: I think the problem is your include `include("../conn.php");`. remember files are only included when page loads. thats why it works on refresh, try adding the `include` outside your function

Comment: Where is your add Director code? the given code executing only once when page load.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot - actually, that is not the problem. I'm connecting fine and it fetches the data smoothly. And the connection file is actually in the pre-folder of this file.

Comment: @Sachink - for the mean time, I'm adding data to `directortb` through the back-end/phpmyadmin.

Comment: Exactly, your php code execute only once when you page load. you need ajax for getting updated data. Right, this is working after page refresh'

Comment: Can you please add the code where you updated the `director table` through ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the form to create a new Director sends an ajax request on submit, that is handled by some PHP code which will update the database with this new entry.

I suggest that, in this PHP code, you return the id of the newly inserted entry. You can then add a "success" function to your ajax call, which will receive that new id once it is inserted, so you can use it to add a new row to your select box.

EDIT:

```
$(function() {
    $("#adddirector").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var directorname = $("#directorname").val();
        //in jQuery you can pass an object, directorname will now show up as $_POST['directorname'] in your PHP handler.
        var dataObj = {'directorname': directorname}

        if(directorname == '')
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeIn(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../action.php",
                data: dataObj,
                //success function should receive the id back as result
                success: function(result){
                    var newId = result;

                    // create and append the new option here with the new id and the given name.
                    var newOption = $('<option></option>');
                    newOption.val(result);
                    newOption.html(directorname);
                    $('.form-control[name="director"]').append(newOption)

                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And make sure that your php file action.php echoes the new id at the end of file! If you want me to take a look at that please post the code in that file also. 
Here's a question from stackoverflow might help you with php. [Getting insert id with insert PDO MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742554/getting-insert-id-with-insert-pdo-mysql)

Comment: Updated with fixed ajax code, make sure you change your php also to echo the newly inserted id. You have to understand that unless you use a framework of some sorts, these dynamic updates don't happen by themselves, you need to code the whole chain (send request, handle request, receive response, update page) yourself.

Comment: Thanks! No need to print out the dropdown via javascript, and just apply the ajax.